# Using UPDATE + SET to change a value to another date's value

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2016

Forgive me if the answer is obvious here, however I have been stuck for days; my unsuccessful query below.

If a 'Retailer' reports sales figures, but not inventory values for a certain day, I want to update that missing value using the value for the day prior.

Here's a sample table:

```
Retailer    Date                      ItemID   Sold   Inventory
Joe's       2017-10-30 00:00:00.000   111111   10     0
Joe's       2017-10-29 00:00:00.000   111111   10     999999
Mary's      2017-10-30 00:00:00.000   123123   10     0
Mary's      2017-10-29 00:00:00.000   123123   10     888888
Betty's     2017-10-30 00:00:00.000   111111   10     499990
Betty's     2017-10-29 00:00:00.000   111111   10     500000
```

And here is the query I'm trying to use:

```
SET T1.Inventory = (SELECT T2.Inventory
                   FROM [dbo].[TEST] T2
                   WHERE CAST(T2.Date AS DATE) = CONVERT(date,getDate()-2))

FROM [dbo].[TEST] T1
WHERE Inventory = '0'
```

Comment: mysql <> sql server please choose one tag and list the version of the correct RDMS

Comment: This seems rather odd. If the inventory all gets sold you want the inventory to be the amount that was available the previous day before the last one was sold. Something seems very off from a logical perspective here.

Comment: @SeanLange I understand that the logic is flawed, this is however how the business would like to view their inventory data in lieu of a proper value delivered from a Retailer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) function instead of `getDate()-2`

And if you want the day before today, you should use GetDate and subtract 1, rather than 2.

If you want the day before the record you are looking at with the same retailer, then you should use t1.Date and make sure you have correlated the subquery:

```
SET T1.Inventory = (SELECT T2.Inventory
                   FROM [dbo].[TEST] T2
                   WHERE CAST(T2.Date AS DATE) = DATEADD(day,-1,CONVERT(date,T1.Date))
                   AND t1.Retailer=t2.Retailer
                   )
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Undoubtedly the reason for the difficulty with updating the inventory column is that the table lacks a unique column which is considered by most to be absolutely essential in any database table. So I have added an identity column RID as a Row ID which is unique.

```
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD RID INT IDENTITY(1,1)

DECLARE @RID INT = (SELECT MIN(RID) FROM T1 WHERE Inventory = 0)
DECLARE @INVZERO INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 WHERE Inventory = 0)
WHILE @INVZERO > 0
BEGIN
UPDATE T1 SET INVENTORY =
(
SELECT INVENTORY FROM T1
WHERE RETAILER = (SELECT RETAILER FROM T1 WHERE RID = @RID)
AND [DATE] = DATEADD(DAY,-1,(SELECT [DATE] FROM T1 WHERE RID = @RID))
)
WHERE RID = @RID
SET @RID = (SELECT MIN(RID) FROM T1 WHERE Inventory = 0 AND RID > @RID)
SET @INVZERO = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 WHERE Inventory = 0)
END

SELECT * FROM T1
```